# Matplotlib: GRID and COLORMAP with TRISURF

Tags: matplotlib, plot, grid, surface, colormap

I want to put a grid on my surface but it doesn't work even with linewidth different from zero, also I would like to plot a colormap that changes the color with Z axis, so the walls should appear with the same color cos they are points at 0.5 in Z. Hope somebody can help me, thanks.

This is the part of my code I'm having problem with:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z,  cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet',4), shade=False,linewidth=0.1, antialiased=False
```

)

[This is my plot with a bad colormap and no grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP8v2.png)

[This is something similar to I want: with grid and a good colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jxRr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(t, t)
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
Z[:, 0] = 0.5
Z[:, -1] = 0.5


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet',256), linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True)
```

[image]

Comment: yes but the problem is that I have three (1D) arrays (so as far as I know trisurf is the only thing that I can use) and also I would like to put a grid over the surface (the same grid of the axes (x,y) but in the blue zone)...thanks

Comment: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Calling gca() with keyword arguments was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4. Starting two minor releases later, gca() will take no keyword arguments. The gca() function should only be used to get the current axes, or if no axes exist, create new axes with default keyword arguments. To create a new axes with non-default arguments, use plt.axes() or plt.subplot().